# About divisibility but it is discrete math. Can someone explain the method?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $$a_0, a_1, . . . , a_n$$ be integers and let $$P (x)$$ be the polynomial
defined as

$$
P(x) = a_0x^n + a_1x^{n−1} + . . . + a_n.
$$

Prove or disprove that if P (x) is divisible by k for all integer x, then $$a_0 ×k!$$
is also divisible by k.

[Click for see origin question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEENx.jpg)

Comment: $a_0k!$ is always divisible by $k$. Please correct the question.

Comment: Wait yeah, ${k!}$ is always going to have a factor of $k$. Maybe a typo??

Comment: @A.Sharma So, if k=5, k!=5! can divide by k?  and How to prove that? I don't get the question

Comment: Do you need the proof how $k!$ is divisible by $k$? Do you know the definition of $k!$ for a positive integer $k$? There is a some typographical mistake. Fix it.

Comment: @A.Sharma I can't post image of question.So, I create link to question sir

Comment: Where is this question from? Is it a test or something? You seem to have typed it out correctly - this is very bizarre. The whole first part of the question seems redundant

Comment: @A.Sharma I got it. Thanks man

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose It is question from assignment. Sorry for type it incorrect form.

Comment: @Munichitk you typed it correctly, which is why I find it so strange. ${k!=k\times (k-1)\times ...\times 1}$, which always will be divisible by $k$ since it has a factor $k$, and hence so will ${a_0\times k!}$ since ${a_0}$ is just another integer. So I'm not sure what the polynomial has to do with it

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose that why I'm not sure that what I have to prove for this question man ;(

Comment: @Munich itk: Almost certainly, the assignment itself  has a typo. Check with your instructor to get a correct statement of the problem.

Comment: True. My mistake.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the problem was supposed to be to prove that $k$ divides every coefficient $a_i$ for $i = 0$ to $n$ (that statement is equivalent to the hypothesis, but requires a reasonable amount of effort for this level to prove). That is a pretty far cry from "$k$ divides $a_0\times k!$". All I can think is that maybe this problem got mixed up with another one.